# Find the complementary and supplementary angles of $48^{\circ}21'12''$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the complementary and supplementary angles of $48^{\circ}21'12''$.
 Please help me I do not know how to do addition and subtraction in DMS system.

Thanks

Comment: its the same as subtracting any numbers, except that instead of borrowing 10, you borrow 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the time is now $3:27$, how would you figure out how long it will be until $6:00$?

It's $2$ hours and $33$ minutes.  The $33$ minutes gets you to $4:00$, and $2$ hours gets you the rest of the way to $6:00$.

So, what angle, when added to $48^{\circ}21'12''$, will get you to $90^{\circ}$?

First, $48''$ gets you to $48^{\circ}22'$.  Then, $38'$ gets you to $49^{\circ}$.  Finally, another $41^{\circ}$ gets you to $90^{\circ}$.

So the complement of the angle is $41^{\circ} 38' 48''$.

Finding the supplement is similar, and the answer is $131^{\circ} 38' 48''$.

Answer (score 1):

$90^{\circ}0'0''-48^{\circ}21'12''$ is similar to, say, $1000-842$ but instead of borrowing 10s you borrow 60s because one degree equals 60 minutes and 1 minute equals 60 seconds.

So, to start with $90^{\circ}0'0''-48^{\circ}21'12''$ becomes $89^{\circ}59'60''-48^{\circ}21'12''$